# How do I send parameters in an HTTP POST request with php?

Tags: php, http

I trying to send a POST request in php but the post fields are in the url.

```
 $project_no        = 1711;
 $group_name        = "name of group";

 $url = urlencode("http://api.example.org/v1/projects?auth_token=xsxxex-xxmczx-66mvmc-9133&project_no=" . $project_no . "&group_name=" . $group_name);

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response)
```

The code above returns a error that says

```
bool(false)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the vars as postfields and send them as an additional curl parameter:

```
$data = array('project_no' => $project_no, 'group_name' => $group_name);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

If the application requires json, you can json_encode() the $data first.

```
$json = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

I don't know the specifics of your application but probably, the auth_token may need to be sent too as an authorization header:

```
$headers = array(
                'Authorization': 'xsxxex-xxmczx-66mvmc-9133',
                //etc);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: I got a error saying "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://api.example.org/p/v1/projects'."}"